# overflow-x div child width

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to find a solution for this case:

I have a div container with a static width and `overflow-x: auto;` 2 child divs, one of them has fixed width, the other one doesn't.

How can I make div without width to have same width as parent?

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/no1lov3sme/U7PhY/1827/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in 2022

```
#parent {
    display: grid;
}
```

Comment: This took me way too long to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just Use 'display: block;' instead of `width`, You can use following CSS for this:

```
#child2 {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U7PhY/1829/)

Answer (score 0):

A div can be of the same width of his parent just by using width:100%;

So you can solve your issue just writing this code on your CSS:

```
#child1{
    width:100%;
}
```

That's the [Demo Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/gianemi2/U7PhY/1831/)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 max-width: 100%;
```

and the width will always stay below or equal to 100% regardless of the content you generate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both the child div of same width as parent div.
you can try this in two ways

```
#child1{
   width:inherit;
   background:green;
   padding:20px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

And you can also use:

```
width:100%;
```

box-sizing property is not compulsory but it helps in managing margin and padding.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution, if you wrap child divs into another div and setting `display: table;` and `width: 100%;` to that div, it solves my problem.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/no1lov3sme/pe2mks4j/2/